# Source for galuta d'galuta גלותא דגלותא?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, language, aramaic, golus-exile

I so clearly remember from my days of Talmud study the phrase גלותא דגלותא, meaning a place that was REALLY far away, seriously in exile, "deep diaspora", totally removed from eretz yisrael.  Maybe it was גלותא של גלותא or גלותא שבגלותא, but I think it was galuta d'galuta.  Can anyone tell me the source for this?  I searched Sefaria and found nothing.  Thank you.

Comment: It is possible that a teacher used it, but as the memory forms in my mind I see it on the page, so I wondered if it was a phrase that anyone could identify.  

As a resident of Oregon, I also live in galuta d'galuta.  In fact I like to call it that, and I was just trying to figure out where that phrase I use came from.   It doesn't feel like something I invented.

Comment: Yes, I have searched Google and Sefaria.  Nothing even close.  And yet my beginner level Aramaic many decades ago would hardly have allowed me to create this phrase myself, and so I wonder and ask....